# Use of TCL script with SQL

Tags: tcl

I want to write a TCL script in which i need to use MySQL. I have to (1) read a file; from that (2) copy data into a SQL table, and after that (3) query data from that table based on requirement. But I am unable to find how to copy data from file to SQL table and then how to query for that table in TCL.

Comment: [This?](http://linuxfocus.org/English/March2004/article331.shtml#331lfindex13)

Comment: You'll want to make sure you're using Tcl version 8.6 so you get [tdbc::mysql](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TdbcmysqlCmd/tdbc_mysql.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
        LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/filename.csv' #loading data from a csv file
        INTO TABLE tablename #tablename is user defined
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' #csv files use comma separated values
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' #till the last column
        IGNORE 1 LINES #ignores the first row if you need



        proc mysql_connect {} {
        variable mysql_dbh ; variable command

        set mysql_host "hostwebsite"
        set mysql_user "username"
        set mysql_password "password"
        set mysql_db "databasename"

        ## loading the driver
        set libmysql_path "driver path"
        if {[catch {load $libmysql_path}]} {
            puts "$command Error: Unable to load mysql file" ; exit
        }

        ## making connection with mysql db
        if {[catch {set ::mysql_dbh [::mysql::connect -h $mysql_host  -u $mysql_user -password $mysql_password -db $mysql_db]}]} {
            puts "$command Error: Unable to connect mysql DB"; exit
        }
        puts "Db connected"
    }     
       proc QueryDisplay {} {

        mysql_connect

        set rows [::mysql::sel $::mysql_dbh "select *from tablename" -list]

        foreach data $rows {
            puts $data
        }

    }
    proc mysql_disconnect {} {
    variable mysql_dbh
    ::mysql::close $::mysql_dbh
}
```